# SOAP UI assertion

Tags: testing, soapui, assertions, assertion

In SOAPUI, for content assertion can we put OR operation.
e.g

> Status = failed OR Unauthorized

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anyway to use OR operations between separate assertions but if you are just checking the content of a message you can use a regular expression inside your Contains Assertion like shown

[image: Contains Assertion]

Answer (score 0):

indirectly this is possible. You can add the script assertion and use if condition.